# Save previous background value of checkbox in Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, button, checkbox

I have a stop button that turns all my checkboxes red.
When I select a checkbox it will turn blue, and when I uncheck it it will turn black.

I want my checkboxes to turn to red when their previous color was red and I want my checkboxes to turn black when their previous color was black.

This is the code I have right now to change the colors.

**Change checked color**

```
for (checkBox in checBoxes)
        {
            checkBox.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
                if (checkBox.isChecked) {
                    checkBox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue_button)
                } else {
                    checkBox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.black_button)
                }
            })

        }
```

**Stop button**

```
stopBtn.setOnClickListener {
for (checkBox in checBoxes)
    {
      checkBox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_button)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create boolean that will tell if user have clicked stop button like this:

```
val isStopped = false
```

Than make your onClickListener lambda function like this:

```
stopBtn.setOnClickListener {
isStopped = true
for (checkBox in checBoxes)
    {
      checkBox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_button)
    }

}
```

And then:

```
for (checkBox in checBoxes)
        {
            checkBox.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
                if (checkBox.isChecked) {
                    checkBox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue_button)
                } else {
                if(isStopped)
                    checkBox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_button)
                else
                    checkBox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.black_button)
                }
            })

        }
```

Comment: This method will not work. Sorry for not mentioning it, but my stop button can turn selected cehckboxes red. This means some checkboxes will be red, and others will be black. 

Using this code i can select a black checkbox, and it will turn red after deselecting it, because isstopped will be true.

Comment: Oh, you can create enum class with color types and then create list of pairs which will hold your checkbox and your type of color for current state and based on that you can check for each checkbox what is current color and then change color as you want.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I almost got it to work with your method. My only problem is that when I select two checkboxes at the same time, it wil overwrite the color value for both of them

Comment: Can you please post your new code again so I can check it ? :D

Comment: I posted my new code in the answers of this question

Answer (score 0):

This is my updated code @dženan-bećirović

**Stop button**

```
stopBtn.setOnClickListener {
for (checkBox in checBoxes)
    {
      checkBox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_button)
      checkBoxBG = checkBox.background
    }

}
```

**Change checked color**

```
for (checkBox in checBoxes)
        {
            checkBox.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
                if (checkBox.isChecked) {
                    checkBoxBG = checkBox.background
                    checkBox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue_button)
                } else {
                       when {
                        checkBoxBG?.getConstantState()?.equals(getDrawable(CheckboxColorStatus.RED.colorValue)?.getConstantState()) == true -> {
                            checkBox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_button)
                        }
                        checkBoxBG?.getConstantState()?.equals(getDrawable(CheckboxColorStatus.BLACK.colorValue)?.getConstantState()) == true -> {
                            checkBox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.black_button)
                        }
                        checkBoxBG?.getConstantState()?.equals(getDrawable(CheckboxColorStatus.YELLOW.colorValue)?.getConstantState()) == true -> {
                            checkBox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yellow_button)
                        }
                    }
                }
            })

        }
```